# ¿Como 'setear' un indice y valor en un arreglo PHP?

Tags: php

En `PHP` tengo un arreglo que a continuación mostrare, yo envió una petición al modelo y este me `retorna el id`, la idea es que yo pueda 'setear'  `'id_company' => $insert_id` en el arreglo `$datos`, pero cuando hice un `array_push($datos, ['id_company' => $insert_id])` me creo un arreglo en ese mismo arreglo y no es la idea.

```
#Este es el arreglo original
$datos = [
          'id_rol_user' => 4,
          'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
          'lastname' => $this->input->post('lastname'),
          'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
          'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
          'password' => sha1($this->input->post('password')),
          'photo' => $ruta,
          'status' => 1,
        ];
#Como deberia de quedar
$datos = [
          'id_rol_user' => 4,
          'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
          'lastname' => $this->input->post('lastname'),
          'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
          'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
          'password' => sha1($this->input->post('password')),
          'photo' => $ruta,
          'status' => 1,
          'id_company' => $insert_id,
        ];
```

Comment: Ya lo solucione, debi haber creado un array_merge, $arreglo = array("id_user_establishment" => $insert_id);
          $datos = array_merge($datos, $arreglo);

Comment: estas usando algun framework para hacer la consulta o directamente con las funciones de PHP ( PDO / Mysqli / etc )  ?

Comment: No necesitas `array_merge` para hacerlo, con hacer: **`$datos['id_company']=$insert_id;`** habría sido suficiente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para agregar el elemento lo creas como directa.

```
$datos['id_company'] = $insert_id;
var_dump($datos);

array(3) { ["id_rol_user"]=> int(4) ["status"]=> int(1) ["id_company"]=> string(12) "100" }
```

Answer (score 1):

**En PHP para cambiar el valor para un determinado índice de un array basta con asignar el nuevo valor**.

Por ejemplo, en el siguiente código cambio el número de manzanas:

```
<?php

$arr_fruits = [
    'apples' => 2,
    'oranges' => 5,
    'pears' => 7,
];
var_dump($arr_fruits);

$arr_fruits['apples'] = 32;
var_dump($arr_fruits);
```

El resultado de la ejecución será:

```
array(3) {
  ["apples"]=>
  int(2)
  ["oranges"]=>
  int(5)
  ["pears"]=>
  int(7)
}
array(3) {
  ["apples"]=>
  int(32)
  ["oranges"]=>
  int(5)
  ["pears"]=>
  int(7)
}
```

Lo que estabas haciendo, con **array_push()** según la [documentación de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-push.php) era *"insertar uno o más elementos al final de un array"*.